# Fractional linear transformations and the extended complex plane in a more abstract context?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, reference-request

Does anyone know of an "abstract algebra-esque" treatment of the extended complex plane and the Mobius transformations?

I am studying complex analysis now, and I am a little frustrated that my familiar algebraic environments have been replaced by apparently more esoteric and delicate structures.

(The book I am using is Ahflors, and I do think he does a good job of explaining the geometry and analysis of the situation. However, some of the connections to algebra, such as homogeneous coordinates, definitely feel a little mysterious to me...)

Comment: Do you know about projective space $CP^n$ and projective transformations?

Comment: Yes, but only in passing. I can see the connection to homogeneous coordinates ... but not the point at infinity. Can you recommend any resources?

Comment: The point $[z:w]$ maps to $z/w$. Do you see what point maps to infinity?

Comment: [1 : 0] should, provided there is some sense of limit...

Comment: Yes, this point is declared to be $\infty$.

Comment: There is an algebraic treatment through algebraic geometry, in which these maps are exactly the algebraic automorphisms of the projective plane $\mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}^{1}$. This group of automorphisms is isomorphic to the group of $\mathbb{C}$-algebra automorphisms of the ring $\mathbb{C}(x)$, which is the field of rational functions in one variable over the complex numbers. The exact association sends $x$ to the fractional transformation.

Comment: Perhaps this is is a direction that will involve more of an algebraic treatment although we are heading through algebraic number theory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form   ,   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group   ,    
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant